# Parse and extract fields from an url field in HiveQL

Tags: regex, hive, hiveql, partitioning

I have this data from a table:

```
id,uri,date_entered,p_id,ads_id
1,http://vegiefood.com/path1/p.php?keyword=veganway&amp;country=france#Ref1,30/JUN/2016,PVEGIEFOOD,GOOGLEADSENSE
2,http://techteacher.com/path1/p.php?keyword=datascience&amp;country=norway#Ref1,15/JAN/2018,PTECHTEACHER,GOOGLEADSENSE
```

I would like to transform or create a new partioned table with the following fields:
fields: id, date, pub_id, advertiser_id, keyword
partition fields: host, country

keyword=veganway

host=vegiefood.com

country=france

and get a table like this

```
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| id          | date          |  pub_id         |       advertiser_id   |  keyword         |   host           | country          |
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| 1           | 30/JUN/2016   | PVEGIEFOOD      | GOOGLEADSENSE         | veganway         | vegiefood.com    | france           |
| 2           | 15/JAN/2018   | PTECHTEACHER    | GOOGLEADSENSE         | datascience      | techteacher.com  | norway           |
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

I don't have any problem with partitioned tables or load data from another table but,
my problem is that I didn't get to parse the uri field [http://vegiefood.com/path1/p.php?keyword=veganway&country=france#Ref1] yet.
I've tried this with [regexp_extract(str, regexp[, idx]) - extracts a group that matches regexp]

May anyone help me or give some clue with regex or another function to parse the uri?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the inbuilt function [`parse_url_tuple`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-parse_url_tuple) to extract the required fields. As the shown url's are in a non-standard format, you might have to do an extra `split` to get the country value. Otherwise you could've used `QUERY:country` in the function.

```
select t.*,parsed.host,parsed.keyword,split((split(query,';')[1]),'=')[1]
from tbl t
lateral view parse_url_tuple(uri,'HOST','QUERY:keyword','QUERY') parsed as host,keyword,query
```

Comment: Great, it worked for me with some little changes ````SELECT t.*,parsed.host,parsed.keyword,
          SPLIT(SPLIT((SPLIT(url,'\\;')[1]),'=')[1],'\\#')[0] AS country
FROM ads_web_stage t
LATERAL VIEW parse_url_tuple(url,'HOST','QUERY:keyword') parsed AS host,keyword;````